# Inner Join of One to Many Relations based on a Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have three tables AppUser, AddressLink and UserAddress. User can be linked to two different address types: "Office" or "Home". The inner join of these tables leading to duplicate records and selecting all linked address. Instead, the address selection needs to be based on a condition; if the Home Type address is present then select the home address, if not select Office type address.
How could I achieve this using Inner Join? Any suggestions?

[image]

Current SQL Query :

```
SELECT
    AU.UserId
   ,AU.UserName
   ,AL.AddressLinkId
   ,AL.AddressType
   ,UA.AddressId
   ,UA.City
   ,UA.ZipCode
   ,UA.CountyCode
FROM AppUser AU
INNER JOIN AddressLink AL
    ON AU.UserId = AL.UserId
INNER JOIN UserAddress UA
    ON UA.AddressId = AL.AddressId
```

And the Result :
[image]

Expected Result : The address selection need to be based on a condition; if the Home Type address is present then select the home address if not select Office type address.

[image]

Comment: It is usually a good idea to supply some data, the code you have tried, what the results were and how they differ from the results that you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select . . .
from appusers u outer apply
     (select top (1) alh.*
      from addresslink alh
      where alh.userid = u.userid 
      order by (case when alh.addresstype = 'Home' then 1 else 2 end)
     ) alh left join
     addresses a
     on alh.addressid = a.addressid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        UserID      =   AU.UserID
    ,   UserName    =   AU.USername
    ,   Phone       =   AU.Phone
    ,   EMail       =   AU.EMail
    ,   CityCode    =   ISNULL(AH.CityCode  , AO.CityCode   )
    ,   ZipCode     =   ISNULL(AH.ZipCode   , AO.ZipCode    )
    ,   CountyCode  =   ISNULL(AH.CountyCode, AO.CountyCode )
FROM            AppUser     AU
    INNER JOIN  AddressLink AL  ON  AL.UserID       =   AU.UserID
    LEFT JOIN   UserAddress AH  ON  AH.AddressID    =   AL.AddressID
                                AND AL.AddressType  =   'Home'
    LEFT JOIN   UserAddress AO  ON  AO.AddressID    =   AL.AddressID
                                AND AL.AddressType  =   'Office'
```